# how to extract the coefficients and exponent of a polynomial as string

Tags: c++, extract, polynomials

hello my problem is that i have to extract the coefficients and exponent of a polynomial given by the user.
 when i tried my code it just worked for the coefficient, and for the exponent it gives me a zero. **p.s** a is just for testing

```
int main() {
    char x[10];
    char y[10];

    char a[100] = "53x2+4x^3";
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != '+'; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != 'x')
        {
            x[i] = a[i];
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != '+'; i++)
    {

        if ((a[i] == 'x') && (a[i + 1] == '^')) {
            y[i] = a[i + 2];
        }
    }
    double w;
    int z;

    w = atof(x);
    z = atoi(y);

    cout << w << endl;
    cout << z << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like `53x2` should be `53x^2`

Comment: still the same problem 

Comment: You are forgetting to null-terminate your C-style strings, among 1001 other things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your coefficient and exponent buffers with null terminators so that they are properly null terminated when the output console reads them.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char x[10] = {'\0'};
    char y[10] = {'\0'};

    char a[100] = "53x^2+4x^3";
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; a[i] != '+'; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != 'x')
        {
            x[j] = a[i];
            j++;
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; a[i] != '+'; i++)
    {

        if ((a[i] == 'x') && (a[i + 1] == '^')) {
            y[j] = a[i + 2];
            j++;
        }
    }
    double w;
    int z;

    w = atof(x);
    z = atoi(y);

    cout << w << endl;
    cout << z << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks!! it worked...but when i changed the condition from a[i] != '+' to a[i] != '+' ||a[i] != '-' it didn't worked